# Can not pass data from UITableView to ViewController using CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is how I am getting the values from CoreData into my UITableView. Note that I have placed a custom cell which is using a Label and an Image View.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? CellTableViewCell
    let cars = carsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell?.lblNoPlate.text = cars.carNoPlate
    cell?.imgView.image = UIImage(data: cars.image!)
    return cell!

}
```

Looking at some tutorials and answers, I was told to pass the values to a new ViewController like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CarDetailsAdminViewController") as! CarDetailsAdminViewController
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? CellTableViewCell

    DvC.NoPlate = (cell?.lblNoPlate.text)!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)


}
```

Everything works perfect. Just that when I tap on any of the cell, it takes to the new viewcontroller, but at the place where I want the string to be passed, it just says "Label". I am guessing Label is the default text which is assigned to any UILabel in swift. It is not being able to pass the actual data which is being displayed in UITableView. Instead, no matter which cell I select, it always shows "Label"

Comment: **Never** get static data form the **view** (the cell) get it always from the **model** (the data source array `cars`). And **never** dequeue a cell outside of `cellForRow`. Only in this method the cell is returned to the table view. And please conform to the naming convention that variable names start always with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dequeueing the cell just get directly the data from your `carsArray`.

Change your `didSelectRowAt` method like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CarDetailsAdminViewController") as! CarDetailsAdminViewController
    DvC.NoPlate = carsArray[indexPath.row].carNoPlate
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Can't believe how easily you did that. Thank you so much!!